# Is it possible to dynamically de-structure return?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I understand this is a very dumb question, I am dumb, maybe confused.

Let us say that I have a module `foo.js` that after doing works returns an object like this bellow,

```
return {something, anotherThing, yetAnotherThing};
```

Now, I want to get those in my `bar.js` and work with, but not with all of them. Maybe sometimes with `something` and sometimes with `anotherThing` etc. So, what I do is,

```
const foo = require('../foo.js')
const { something } = foo()
```

Then I work with `something` in my files.

The problem here is, most of the time, I need `something` or `anotherThing` on a random basis. Like I do not know which one I will need. Sometimes I need all of them and somethings I need only one or two.

So, is it possible to write a function that dynamically gets the destructed variables and work with them? For example, if I create an array of the things needed from the `foo` file and pass that array to a function that takes element from the array to get variable from `foo.js` and work with it? An incorrect code example of what I am saying will be,

```
const iAmWrong = ( arr) => {
  
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const { arr[i] } = foo();
    }

    arr[i]();
};
```

There must be a way to achieve this right? Maybe not how I am thinking it is in code but I hope it is not impossible.

Please help.

Comment: If your code is this dynamic and undecidable, then the last thing you want is *dynamic destructuring*. That's basically *variable variables*, which basically never makes sense either. Just don't destructure, and dynamically access the object's properties like `obj[prop]` instead.

Comment: Can you please give me any code sample?

Comment: Of something that's not possible? No.

Comment: I see reference to another question, I will check that, thank you for marking that.

Comment: Also relevant: [“Variable” variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530)

Comment: "*Sometimes I need all of them and somethings I need only one or two.*" - so just destructure to create variables for all of them, so that you have them available if you need them. No harm done with unused variable values.